# Changing UIBarButtonItem font on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

`UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes()` doesn't work on iOS 13.

Comment: You have to provide some code that you are working with this part

Comment: Your syntax is of Swift4, if you are using SwiftUI then it is not going to work.

Comment: @Hima it has nothing to do with SwifUI. It just doesn't work in iOS 13 as it used to.

Comment: Look into the new way of setting up the appearance for UINavigationBar and UIToolBar. Part of setting those up are settings for button appearance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way iOS handles global appearances appears to have changed. You'll need to add a condition check for iOS 13 and above and then add your attributes as shown below.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let standard = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    standard.configureWithTransparentBackground()

    // TITLE STYLING
    standard.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, .font: "FONTNAME"]

    // NAV BUTTON STYLING
    let button = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(style: .plain)
    button.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: .white, .font: "FONTNAME"]
    standard.buttonAppearance = button

    let done = UIBarButtonItemAppearance(style: .done)
    done.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: .white, .font: "FONTNAME"]
    standard.doneButtonAppearance = done

    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = standard
} else { 

    // Your previous styling here for 12 and below

}
```

Check out [this](https://sarunw.com/posts/uinavigationbar-changes-in-ios13) post for more. I found it really useful in understanding the new updates.